# Wrap tags inside zend form

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

How do I wrap dt dd tags in zend form. The previous format of my html code that generated is this:

```
<dt id="email-label">
   <label for="email" class="optional">Username(email):</label>
</dt>
<dd id="email-element">
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
</dd>
```

The zend code for that is:

```
$form->addElement('text', 'email');
$usernameElement = $form->getElement('email');
$usernameElement->setLabel('Username(email):');
```

I want these two tags will be wrapped inside one parent tag looks like this:

```
<div id="form_wrapper">
    <dt id="email-label">
        <label for="email" class="optional">Username(email):</label>
    </dt>
    <dd id="email-element">
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="">
    </dd>  
</div>
```

So how could I do that in zend framework?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$usernameElement->setDecorators(array(
     'ViewHelper',
     'Label',
      new Zend_Form_Decorator_HtmlTag(array('tag' => 'div','id'=>'form_wrapper')) 
));
```